# How to access to a user public picture, just with photo id

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

When a user loggin in my app, i get, trough facebook API, the public pictures id, by the code below and save that in DB. Now i want to access to that photos by the url generated by the picture id. The problem is when other users of the app try to access to that link. It throws an exception becouse its required an access token.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id");
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/photos",
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("FBPics", "teste");
                }
            }
    );
    request.executeAsync();
```

The link that i receive is like that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?width=250&height=250
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: are you using a user token for that link/api call?

Comment: But what i want is to access to the photo, without the token, just with a link returned by the code posted by me.

Comment: pretty sure that´s not possible anymore

Comment: So how can i see the other user public photos, when i'm using the app?

Comment: ...by using the access token to get the url of the photo?

Comment: But  it's not possible if i put the id of the other user. Imagine that im using the app and i want to see your photos. What should i use in this string "/me/photos" ?

Comment: you cannot get my photos without me authorizing your app...